# How to reduce read/write to excel time in python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 640,000 rows of data in excel.

I want to append some rows to the data so I used
`pd.read_excel` and `pd.concat([excel, some_data])`.

After that, I used `df.to_excel()` to write back to excel.

But, `read_excel` is taking a long time, about 3 minutes, and `to_excel` is too.

How can I fix it?

```
def update_mecab(new_word_list):
    user_dicpath='C:\\mecab\\user-dic\\custom.csv'

    dictionary=pd.read_excel('./first_dictionary.xlsx')

    dictionary=pd.concat([dictionary, new_word_list])

    part_names= {
        '일반 명사' : 'NNG',
        '고유 명사' : 'NNP',
        '의존 명사' : 'NNB',
        '수사' : 'NR',
        '대명사' : 'NP',
        '동사' : 'VV',
        '형용사' : 'VA',
        '보조 용언' : 'VX',
        '관형사' : 'MM',
        '일반 부사' : 'MAG',
        '접속 부사' : 'MAJ',
        '감탄사' : 'IC'
    }

    new_word_pt=new_word_list.replace({"part":part_names})

    user_dict=open(user_dicpath, 'a', encoding="UTF-8")

    for index, item in new_word_pt.iterrows() :
        custom_word=item['word']+',*,*,*,'+item['part']+',*,T,'+item['word']+',*,*,*,*,*\n'
        user_dict.write(custom_word)

    user_dict.close()
    del user_dict
    dictionary=dictionary.reset_index()
    dictionary=dictionary[['word', 'part']]

    dictionary.to_excel('first_dictionary.xlsx', sheet_name = "Sheet_1", index=None)
    subprocess.call("powershell C:\\mecab\\add-userdic-win.ps1")
```

Comment: Have you tried using CSV instead of xlsx? Excel data format is naturally bulkier and the machinery needed to parse and write it will be heavier. Also, `pd.read_csv()` is very optimized whereas `pd.read_excel()` relies on additional xlsx reader libraries like `openpyxl`. If the issue is really the read/write speed, then there is not much you can do about it without using a faster language, or a more optimized library

Comment: It sounds like, as well, that you're not looking to reduce the _append_ time (as the question states), but rather the _read_ and _write_ times to excel.